# All click event handlers firing when a single click event triggered

Tags: javascript

I've tried to organize my Javascript using IIFEs to make things more modular. However, I'm getting some strange behaviour I can't explain.

I have two divs:

```
<div id="one">foo</div>
<div id="two">bar</div>
```

I have some IIFEs to:

- lazy-load and cache elements
- define event listeners
- bind event listeners
- handle initialization

I try to assign a click handler to each `div`, but when I click on either `div`, all handlers fire. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/u61vet1g/

```
(function(foobar) {
    foobar.elements = (function() {
        var one, two;

        return{
            one: function(){
                return one || (one = $('#one'));
            },
            two: function(){
                return two || (two = $('#two'));
            }   
        }
    })();

    foobar.eventListeners = (function(elems){       

        return {
            oneOnClick: function(e) {
                alert('1');
            },
            twoOnClick: function(e) {
                alert('2');
            }
        }
    })(foobar.elements);

    foobar.bindEventListeners = (function(elems, listeners) {
        return function () {
            $(document).on('click', elems.one(), listeners.oneOnClick);

            $(document).on('click', elems.two(), listeners.twoOnClick);
        }
    })(foobar.elements, foobar.eventListeners);

    foobar.init = function (options) {
        foobar.bindEventListeners();
    };
})(window.foobar = window.foobar || {});
foobar.init();
```

Comment: because you handle both on `document`. Try click on white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delegated Listener requires a jQuery selector not an object (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '#two', listeners.twoOnClick);
```

So if you change your `foobar.elements()` to return a selector string (eg:`'#two'`) it works:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/moob/u61vet1g/1/

Comment: Good point. But no reason to use delegated listeners here. `1 handler` Vs `1 handler`.

Comment: @vp_arth Presumably there's a reason why the OP uses event delegation. Maybe the elements are replaced following a later ajax call or something. Who knows?

Answer (score 3):

> I have some IIFEs to

Whoa. These look totally over-engineered.

> when I click on either div, all handlers fire. Why?

Because you're not binding the handlers to the elements, but to `document`:

```
$(document).on('click', …);
```

The jQuery objects passed for the second argument will become the [`data` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Instead, use

```
elems.one().on('click', listeners.oneOnClick);
elems.two().on('click', listeners.twoOnClick);
```

Comment: The script I'm working on is much more complex than this, so modularization, and I drew inspiration from https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/glimpse.js But I'm happy to entertain any constructive criticism.

Comment: Yeah, for a more complex script it may be useful; for the bit you posted it's overkill. I'm still suspicious about those nested IEFEs, I think you either should omit the outermost one (and move `window.foobar = window.foobar || {}` to the top of your script), or remove the inner ones (and just declare `elemns` and `eventlisteners` as local variables to the outer one)

Answer (score 2):

This happened because you handle both on document.
Try click on white and you get both alerts too.

Try followed syntax:

```
elems.one().on('click', listeners.oneOnClick);
```